# Node js. Прекратить обрабатывать запрос по таймеру

Tags: timeout, node.js

Проблема. Посылаю на сервак функцию. Она может быть какой угодно(например на сервер попала функция с бесконеченым циклом, то понятно, что все станет.
Вопрос, как этого избежать?Т.е. например установить таймаут, по итогам которого сервак принудительно ответит на запрос и прекратит выполнение цикла.

Comment: Скорее всего, это невозможно. Javascript - однопоточный язык, и прервать бесконечный цикл можно только остановкой процесса.